# Cost of time-stamping as a method of concurrency control with Entity Framework

Tags: performance, entity-framework, concurrency

In concurrency, in optimistic concurrency the way to control the concurrency is using a timestamp field. However, in my particular case, not all the fields need to be controlled in respect to concurrency.

For example, I have a products table, holding the amount of stock. This table has fields like description, code... etc. For me, it is not a problem that one user modifies these fields, but I have to control if some other user changes the stock.

So if I use a timestamp and one user changes the description and another changes the amount of stock, the second user will get an exception.

However, if I use the field stock instead of concurrency exception, then the first user can update the information and the second can update the stock without problems.

Is it a good solution to use the stock field to control concucrrency or is it better to always use a timestamp field?

And if in the future I need to add a new important field, then I need to use two fields to control concurrency for stock and the new one? Does it have a high cost in terms of performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the definition of *optimistic concurrency*:

> In the field of relational database management systems, optimistic concurrency control (OCC) is a concurrency control method that assumes that multiple transactions can complete without affecting each other, and that therefore transactions can proceed without locking the data resources that they affect. ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency))

Clearly this definition is abstract and leaves a lot of room for your specific implementation.

Let me give you an example. A few years back I evaluated the same thing with a bunch of colleagues and we realized that in our application, on some of the tables, it was okay for the concurrency to simply be based on the fields the user was updating.

So, in other words, as long as the fields they were updating hadn't changed since they gathered the row, we'd let them update the row because the rest of the fields really didn't matter **and** and row was going to get refreshed on udpate anyway so they would get the most recent changes by other users.

So, in short, I would say what you're doing is just fine **and** there aren't really any hard and fast rules. It really depends on what you need. If you need it to be more flexible, like what you're talking about, then make it more flexible -- simple.

Comment: well, in my case at least I will have two fields, stock and a reference to other product, so in this case I need two fields to control the optimistic, instead of one if I use a timestamp.

Comment: And that's just fine. In the example I described above it was variable. If the user updated three fields then we used three fields in the WHERE clause, if they only updated one then it was just one field, it was flexible.